# UINavigationController change navigation bar tint color globally and programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, colors, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

This code can change color of a `UINavigationBar` everywhere within the application. However, I noticed that **it does not change the `UIColor` of the `UINavigationBar` used by** `UINavigationController` (mine comes from a `UIStoryboard`).

```
UIColor* navBarColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random()%100/100.0 
                                       green:arc4random()%100/100.0 
                                        blue:arc4random()%100/100.0 
                                       alpha:1];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navBarColor];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha:0.7];
```

**Is there a way to access the `appearance` object of a `UINavigationController's` navigation bar?** I know how to set tints of individual controllers, but I want to have a global control over how they look.

Update:
This was my mistake, the code does change the `UIColor` of all `UINavigationBars`, but it requires the root navigation controller to be covered and uncovered(for example presenting a modal view controller), then it will re-draw itself with new `UIColors`!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete solution which changes the navbar color instantly and remembers the preference for subsequent launches can be found here: 
[iPhone iOS how to redraw UINavigationBar on demand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484741/iphone-ios-how-to-redraw-uinavigationbar-on-demand)

Answer (score 19):

Now in iOS 8 we can set tint color by this :-

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 15):

You can change bar colours globally using `appearance` proxy:

```
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                           UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                           [UIColor whiteColor],  
                                           UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
textTitleOptions = 
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                            UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Note that `UITextAttributeTextColor` and `UITextAttributeShadowColor` have been deprecated - use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `NSShadowAttributeName` instead.

Answer (score 14):

When you declaring your `UINavigationController`, try this:

```
UINavigationController *myNavController = 
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myRootViewController];
myNavController.navigationBar.tintColor = 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random() % 100 / 100.0f
                    green:arc4random() % 100 / 100.0f
                     blue:arc4random() % 100 / 100.0f
                    alpha:1.0f];
```